# How to create up lines in charts in Microsft Excel 2013 for Windows?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Under Design > Add Chart Elements > Lines you can easily add drop lines to your charts. However, there is no option that I can see for doing the opposite---creating upwards trending lines in my chart, to visually indicate a minimum value. How can I accomplish this?

Bonus kodus if you can show me how to cap these lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Error Bars to a line chart.  Set the direction to "Plus".

If you want the error bar to rise to a specific value, you need to calculate the value in the sheet and use a custom error amount that points to that range.

[image]